# FlutterFire Analytics shows a wrong user usage time

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-analytics

Since we moved from a native Android and iOS app to Flutter, our user interaction time on Firebase Analytics went nuts. We went from 5 minutes use time on average to almost 90 minutes. That's impossible.

Here's the graph to showcase the evolution. You can clearly see when the Flutter version replaced the Android one.

How to fix it?

[image: Impossible interaction time with FlutterFire]